# Razor asp- tag helper is not recognized

Tags: razor, refactoring, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have following HTML code

```
<a asp-action="index">Demo</a>
```

the `asp` tag is not recognized by Visual Studio 2022

[image]

and when I build and run the solution the `asp` tag is not translated into the html code

[image]

There are no warnings, errors or JavaScript errors.

I copied the `Views` folder from `.NET Core 2.1 MVC` into the `.NET 6 Core MVC` project. The `Index.cshtml` file has `BuildAction = Content` property as other files in the `View` folder.

What might went wrong, why the tag helper is not translated?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The reason was that I had file `ViewImports.cshtml` but it should be named `_ViewImports.cshtml`. I don't know how that happened, but in this discussion https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9d42158-3bb6-490c-a59f-579eedeb060f/razor-not-rendering-tag-helper?forum=aspdotnetcore the another user had the same issue